# Adding and Removing Required Tag Dynamically in HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, required

I have a select option with many values, I need to toggle a field required or not based on the select option value, tried all possible solutions such as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});

function toggleFields(sel) {
 var valuee = sel.value;  
 alert (valuee);


 if (valuee < 7){


    //$("#comment").setAttribute("required",""); 
    alert("Removed");
    $('#comment').required = false;                //Correct
    $('#comment').removeAttribute("required");     //Correct
}

else{
    $('#comment').required = true;                       //Correct
    $('#comment').setAttribute("required", ""); 
    alert("Set");
}
```

}

a running example can be found into this fiddle

[Fiddle Link is below](https://jsfiddle.net/tjwoo1y7/1/)

Comment: You're calling js scripts *after* calling jQuery. It needs to be the first script you call.

Comment: for me the example not running, and my consol says: ReferenceError: toggleFields is not defined (FF 44.0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code should be inside `$(document).ready(function () {  /*your code here */  }` not under it.

EDIT: or it should be set up to not call any jquery code before jquery is loaded. You may want to remove the inline function and set up an event handler inside your script

Also, what is `$('comment')`? It should be a selector eg. `$('#comment')` or an element eg. `$('div')`.

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/tjwoo1y7/11/

```
 $('#comment').attr("required", false);
 $('#comment').attr("required", true);
```

Comment: when adding the function to document.ready, it says toggleFields is not defined

Comment: do you mean in jsfiddle, or on your own page?

Comment: actually, in http://jsfiddle.net/tjwoo1y7/2/ where you put the code inside the ready function it says $ is not defined. Problem is that you haven't properly set up your fiddle... press the tidy button to see. Then press the javascript radar icon and set up to use jquery

Comment: well, like I said your fiddle is not properly set up. I did and found other propblems. Also, again what is $('comment') ? It's not a selector or an element.

Comment: I updated it just right now, kindly check [link](https://jsfiddle.net/tjwoo1y7/7/)

Comment: ok I updated the fiddle: added jquery and changed load type to no wrap - in <head> ... click the javascript radar icon to see that. I'm not sure scripts and sources you put in html field will work, but even if they work you need to use valid sources!  https://jsfiddle.net/tjwoo1y7/10/

Comment: I tried the fiddle this morning, its working and giving the alerts, but still the field isn't set to required yet. I still can submit the form without the field #comment.

Comment: well, finally getting to the real problem. Which element is #comment?

Comment: its the next to COC Number Label.

Comment: well, $("#comment") is targeting an element with id="comment". That element doesn't have that. So I added it and I changed your code

Comment: I tried the code on my running project, none was running, I created a new fiddle to check, can you assist please [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltkmjfe9/)

Comment: I don't see id="comment" attribute for that element. Maybe you did not add that in your own page